# Não consigo falar com classe específica no css

Tags: html, css

Fiz um menu e agora estou tentando estilizar um menu dropdown, mas não estou conseguindo falar com o `a` da `.dropdown-content`. Percebi que o `.header-menu ul li a` está hierarquicamente acima da `.dropdown-content a`, mas não descubro como mudar isso. Segue o código:

https://jsfiddle.net/zxvLwdjw/

Edit: Adicionei o código aqui e vou tentar ser mais específico

Não estou conseguindo falar com o `a` da classe `.dropdown-content`, como podem ver os estilos que coloquei nessa classe não estão funcionando, o `a` não está com `60px` de altura, a cor do texto não é branca, o texto não está alinhado a esquerda...

Já tentei atribuir uma classe para o `a` e não funcionou.

```css
.header-menu {
 height: auto;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 0;
}

.header-menu ul li {
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
}

.header img {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 60px;
 padding: 20px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover {
 background: #fd1616; /*Vermelho*/
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background: #111112;
 width: 130px;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background: #fd1616;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="ps4.html">PS4</a></li>
     <li><a href="xboxone.html">XBOX ONE</a></li>
     <li><a href="pc.html">PC</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="outrosconsoles.html">Outros Consoles</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#">PS3</a>
     <a href="#">XBOX 360</a>
     <a href="#">WII U</a>
     </div>
     </li>
     <li><a href="esports.html">eSports</a></li>
     <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
     <li><a href="videos.html">Vídeos</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Comment: Ponha o trecho relevante do código na pergunta. Pode manter o link como complemento, claro, mas as perguntas não podem depender de conteúdo externo (e nem é legal as pessoas terem que ficar consultando coisa fora do site para ajudar). Aproveite ao [edit] para explicar melhor qual é o resultado que precisa, e não só como está tentando resolver.

Comment: Porque você não atribui uma classe as tags <a> ?

Comment: Editei com o código e mais informações. Já tentei atribuir uma classe para o <a> e não funcionou

Comment: @GabrielSouza melhorou bastante, mas de qual dos A vc fala?

Comment: @GabrielSouza tá com 60 px sim, só que tá com padding. Ponha um padding:0 que é pra resolver. Essas coisas você vê fácil usando o inspetor do browser.

Comment: @GabrielSouza Creio que se você mudar o CSS do `.dropdown-content a` para `.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a` você consegue utilizar as propriedades. Ou você pode utilizar `!important` no `color` e no `text-align`, apesar disso futuramente poder te trazer problemas

Comment: Já ouviu falar em bootstrap?

Comment: Do jeito que tá indo, só falta alguém recomendar jQuery agora.

Comment: Já usou jQuery ?

Comment: Já ouviu a palavra do nosso salvador [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)?

Comment: @Gumball agora não falta mais kkkk

Comment: Valeu William! Apenas colocando a classe .header-menu ul li na frente já resolveu

Comment: @Willian poste como resposta, assim o Gabriel pode marcar como aceita e fechar o assunto

Comment: @GabrielSouza Se puder marcar a resposta como aceita, eu agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o que você apresentou, você pode resolver o problema mudando o `.dropdown-content` para `.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content`, assim ele irá dar preferência para as configurações que deseja. Ou você pode utilizar o `!important` logo após definir os valores de `color`e `text-align`, porem utilizar ele pode futuramente te trazer problemas ao dar manutenção ao site.

Ele ficaria assim:

```
.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, da forma que você esta referenciando os elementos no css dificulta a manutenção, eu recomendaria desenvolver classes para os elementos, peguei seu html e desenvolvi um exemplo:

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav{
  background-color: #3498db;
  display: block;
}

.menu{
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-item, .menu-link{
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item:hover{
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.menu-item:hover .sub-menu{
  display: block;
}

.menu-link{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}

.sub-link{
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  color: #ecf0f1;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sub-link:hover{
  border-left:3px solid #333;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="ps4.html" class="menu-link">PS4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="xboxone.html" class="menu-link">XBOX ONE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="pc.html" class="menu-link">PC</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="outrosconsoles.html" class="menu-link">Outros Consoles</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        <a href="#" class="sub-link">PS3</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub-link">XBOX 360</a>
        <a href="#" class="sub-link">WII U</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Repare nas novas classes que adicionei em seu html e como ficou mais fácil entender o que é oque.